# php how to count posts and display it as "(5/1)" in html

Tags: html

How to count posts in PHP in my case uploaded files(pictures) and than display it as (5/1) 5 being total posts on site and 1 being number of post from current user logged in.

Code for uploading the picture:

```
include_once('./server.php');
include_once('./session.php');

$tekst = $_POST['naslov_slike'];
$userId = $_SESSION['id'];

$query_post = "INSERT INTO posts (naslov_slike, id_users) 
    VALUES ('".$tekst."', $userId)";

mysqli_query($db, $query_post);

$postId = mysqli_insert_id($db);

if (!empty($_FILES['slike']))  
{
    $koncnica = explode('.', $_FILES['slike']['name']);
    $novoIme = time().".".end($koncnica);
    $koncnaSlika = "./images/".$novoIme;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['slike']['tmp_name'], $koncnaSlika)) 
    {
        $slike = "UPDATE posts SET slike = '".$novoIme."' WHERE id_posts = ".$postId;

        mysqli_query($db, $slike);

    }
}

header('Location: ./');



?>
```

Comment: Make 2 queries, one for total post count for the user, and the other for total post count overall.

Comment: i did it for total count:                                                                                  <?php
    $post_query = "SELECT count(*) AS total FROM posts ";

    $post_result = mysqli_query($db, $post_query);

    $post = mysqli_fetch_array($post_result);
?>                                                                                                                                     but i am struggling with post count for the user....